# getting max(dict_name.values()) to ignore strings

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I am using Python 2.7 to get the name associated with the maximum value in a dictionary called 'names' where the value for each name is a number (specifically, their annual compensation). I have used the code 

`max(names.values())`

The problem is that a few of the values are missing and coded 'NaN', which happens to be the maximum value in Python's eyes. Is there some way to limit the max() function to numeric values and induce it to ignore non-numeric values?

Once I get the maximum value, is there a way to use that maximum value to find the name (the dictionary key) associated with it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could pre-filter out all strings:

```
seq = [x for x in names.values() if not isinstance(x, str)]
print max(seq)
```

Or you could supply a key function that gives hugely negative values for strings:

```
print max(names.values(), key=lambda x: x if not isinstance(x, str) else float("-inf"))
```

Comment: Thank, Keven. Your answer works perfectly for the question I asked, but it made me realize that I asked the wrong question. I should have framed my question better. I am trying to find the name of the person with the highest salary. Your code has obviously found that highest salary. Can I use that to get the name associated with that value? Dictionaries are set up to be accessed by keys, not values, so it is not clear to me how to do that. Thanks!

Comment: In that case I would do `max(d.keys(), key=lambda x: names[x] if not isinstance(names[x], str) else float("-inf"))`